# Xamarin CollectionView items fit evenly

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, collectionview

I'm working on a Xamarin Android project and have a `CollectionView` with some dynamic `Button` items (currently 6), but they appear to be clipped off or "goes outside the box" (I hope you understand - I don't know the exact description of this).

Example code (simplified):

```
<CollectionView
   ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
   ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Button Text="Text" />
      </DataTemplate>                               
   </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Result screen shot:

[image]

Notice that only 4½ items are displayed in the image - the rest are "cut off" or "clipped off" i.e. goes outside (or whatever you call it) and not displayed.

I can get my desired result, if I manually insert the items in a grid (and using no binding).

See this example code:

```
<Grid ColumnSpacing="8">
   <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Text" />
   <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Text" />
   <Button Grid.Column="2" Text="Text" />
   <Button Grid.Column="3" Text="Text" />
   <Button Grid.Column="4" Text="Text" />
   <Button Grid.Column="5" Text="Text" />
</Grid>
```

Result screen shot:

[image]

So how to make sure that bindable items within a `CollectionView` are fit nicely evenly, i.e. not clipped off (and having same auto-width)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please post a screenshot illustrating the problem, and post the relevant code/xaml.

Comment: please add some code and attach media if its necessary

Comment: OP is not responding to comments, voting to close

Comment: Sorry. I have updated my description with code/xaml and screen shots.

Comment: The CollectionView is designed to scroll. You told the CollectionView to layout it's items in a horizontal list: `ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"`, so it's doing exactly that and allowing to scroll through the items. The CollectionView has several different [layout options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#vertical-grid) for you to choose from to give the layout you need. If you don't want scrolling, take a look at using a [BindableLayout](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,`CollectionView` is a view for presenting lists of data using different layout specifications. It aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to `ListView`.

And `CollectionView` should be used for presenting lists of data that require scrolling or selection.
Just as Andrew, in your code we could find that the value of property `ItemsLayout` is `HorizontalList`, so the CollectionView will scroll horizontally if content can't be fully displayed horizontally.

```
 ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
```

From document [Xamarin.Forms CollectionView Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout),we know that

By default, a CollectionView will display its items in a vertical list. However, any of the following layouts can be used:

- **Vertical list** – a single column list that grows vertically as new
  items are added.
- **Horizontal list** – a single row list that grows horizontally as new
  items are added.
- **Vertical grid** – a multi-column grid that grows vertically as new
  items are added.
- **Horizontal grid** – a multi-row grid that grows horizontally as new
  items are added.

These layouts can be specified by setting the ItemsLayout property to class that derives from the ItemsLayout class. This class defines the following properties:

- **Orientation**, of type ItemsLayoutOrientation, specifies the direction
  in which the CollectionView expands as items are added.
- **SnapPointsAlignment**, of type SnapPointsAlignment, specifies how snap
  points are aligned with items.
- **SnapPointsType**, of type SnapPointsType, specifies the behavior of
  snap points when scrolling.

For more , you can check official document [CollectionView Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction)   and [CollectionView Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout).

**In addition**,if you don't want scroll, a bindable layout can be used when the data to be displayed doesn't require scrolling or selection. For more information, see [Bindable Layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts) in Xamarin.Forms.

Please refer to the following code:

```
    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
         Orientation="Horizontal" >
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Text="Text" WidthRequest="50" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your comments.

I was able to find another working solution on how to nicely fit my items using a `FlexLayout` control as my container instead.

Code example:

```
<StackLayout>
   <FlexLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
      JustifyContent="SpaceBetween"
      Wrap="NoWrap">
      <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Null}">
            <Button FlexLayout.Basis="14%" Text="{Binding Text}" />
         </DataTemplate>
      </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
   </FlexLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: As per [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/bindable-layouts): *Bindable layouts should only be used when the collection of items to be displayed is small, and scrolling and selection isn't required. While scrolling can be provided by wrapping a bindable layout in a ScrollView, this is not recommended as bindable layouts lack UI virtualization. When scrolling is required, a scrollable view that includes UI virtualization, such as ListView or CollectionView, should be used. Failure to observe this recommendation can lead to performance issues.*